# How do I assign a region to programmatically created block?

Tags: 8, blocks

Hi after following this [guide](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/264177/how-do-i-create-multiple-blocks) I was able to create multiple blocks.
But I have couple of issues.

1. Blocks are not created instantly need to clear cache but cant find a way to do it instantly (solution might be clearing block cache but how ?).
2. I need to assign region to the block while creating itself but cant do so .
3. I want to have x content for x *block id* and y content for y *block id* cant write a filter condition as I cant get *block id* of the blocks.

Basically I want to achieve all the D7 module's functionality in D8.

If anyone have an idea please help me.

Comment: Well of course you need to clear cache when adding new block definitions - the system needs to pick up the annotation class that was added.

Comment: Yes, just like I commented over there, this is by design. Blocks in Drupal 8 are placed by creating them, they don't exist by default. If you want to automatically put them somewhere then you need to create a new block config entity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's expected. You can do it from code if needed. The following are the steps to follow.

1. Settings definition is done as in [block.block.test_block.yml](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21block%21tests%21modules%21block_test%21config%21install%21block.block.test_block.yml/8.2.x). Place that file, after editing it, in my_module/config/install and you're set. A quick hack is managing the block settings manually in a local environment and export them from /admin/config/development/configuration/single/export.
2. Import your settings, which can be done using code similar to the following one.

   ```php
   use Drupal\Core\Config\FileStorage;

   $config_path = drupal_get_path('module', 'my_module') . '/config/install';
   $source = new FileStorage($config_path);
   $config_storage = \Drupal::service('config.storage');
   $block_config = 'block.block.test_block';
   $config_storage->write($block_config , $source->read($block_config));
   ```

   Block settings are theme dependent.

For dynamic allocation of blocks, you can load and alter the block entity like this.

```php
use Drupal\block\Entity\Block;

$block = Block::load('test_block');
$block->setRegion('my_region');
$block->save();
```