# How can I create two blocks at once from the same custom module?

Tags: 8, blocks

I have figured out how to create a block from a custom module, by creating a ./src/Plugin/Block folder, then creating a PHP script inside it, with the following code:

```
<?php
namespace Drupal\MY_MODULE_NAME\Plugin\Block;

use Drupal\Core\Access\AccessResult;
use Drupal\Core\Block\BlockBase;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Session\AccountInterface;

/**
 * Provides a block with a simple text.
 *
 * @Block(
 *   id = "BLOCK_MACHINE_NAME",
 *   admin_label = @Translation("BLOCK_DISPLAY_TITLE"),
 * )
 */
class MyBlock extends BlockBase {
  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function build() {

    $html = "MY_BLOCK_CONTENTS_HERE";
    return [
      '#markup' => $this->t( $html ),
    ];
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  protected function blockAccess(AccountInterface $account) {
    return AccessResult::allowedIfHasPermission($account, 'access content');
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function blockForm($form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $config = $this->getConfiguration();
    return $form;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function blockSubmit($form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $this->configuration['my_block_settings'] = $form_state->getValue('my_block_settings');
  }
}
```

My question is, if I want my Custom Module to create a second block, how would I do that?

Do I just create a second script under ./src/Plugin/Block using this same format, and change the BLOCK_MACHINE_NAME and BLOCK_DISPLAY_NAME values?

If I change the line:

```
class MyBlock extends BlockBase { ... }
```

to

```
class MySecondBlock extends BlockBase { ... }
```

... can I keep all the functions under it the same, eg:

```
class MySecondBlock extends BlockBase {
    public function build() { ... }
    protected function blockAccess() { ... }
    public function blockForm() { ... }
    public function blockSubmit() { ... }
}
```

Or is it more complicated than that? Do I need to try and build both Blocks from within the same script, and a single set of functions?

Any advice is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: The method is exactly the same as creating your first block. Just make sure the filename, the class name, and the machinename of the plugin all differ from the first block you created.

Comment: if you want to create blocks dynamically then you can use Block Derivaties. For reference you can check here. https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/264177/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can a create as many block plugins as you want within a single module. Each of these plugins must have a unique ID in annotation. In order to reduce code duplication you can create an abstract class that would hold all common functionality. Other classes can extend it and override methods that need a different implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to add a block category as well.

```
/**
 * Provides a block with a simple text.
 *  * @Block(
 *   id = "BLOCK_MACHINE_NAME",
 *   admin_label = @Translation("BLOCK_DISPLAY_TITLE"),
 *   category = @Translation("SUCH_AS_VIEWS_MENU ETC") 
 * )
 */
```