# How can I programmatically create a block type?

Tags: 8, entities, blocks

I want to create a block type that has a couple of fields, a template and attached JavaScript.

I want that the user in my site will be able to create blocks of this type just like they create a custom block: through /block/add/myBlockType.

I would like ideally to have it all done programmatically but I dont mind manually creating my block type though "admin/structure/block/block-content/types" or with configuration files.

The thing is I have been scraping google for two days already and I don't manage to figure out how to programmatically create a block type

And this that the information is not easily found on Google makes me think that instead I need to create my type with configuration and then apply my plugin on creation of a new block but im still not sure how to do that and what my plugin needs to extend.

How can I do that?

Comment: When creating custom block types programatically you create a `Block` plugin. There are a ton of guides how to do that, here's one. https://www.valuebound.com/resources/blog/drupal-8-how-to-create-a-custom-block-programatically

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I have already written this block plugin. and I have found tons of guides just like the one you linked here. but they all finish with one single block. I want that my user will be able to create as many blocks as they wish.

Comment: Oh, this works in panels, but not in core. You have to add a deriver to the block plugin in order for it to work. Look at this post for help. https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/264177/how-do-i-create-multiple-blocks

Comment: The discussion is confusing. A custom block type is the bundle of the block content entity (like content type for nodes) and not a block plugin. @crab, please make it more clear what you want to create.

Comment: I want to create block type! I think my question is clear. I can delete the last part if its confusing.

Comment: Perhaps you want to export a block type to a module so that it is created when the module is installed, like this question for paragraph types: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/283090/export-paragraph-bundle-with-drupal-console

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue and I hope I have resolved it.

Your algorithm is next:

1. Create your own module
2. Create file <your_module>.install
3. There must be at least one hook `hook_install` (I have used two: `hook_install` and `hook_uninstall`)
4. Inside install hook:

   - create a new block type
   - create fieldStorageConfig
   - create fieldConfig
   - set component for form and view display

My code:

```
<?php

use Drupal\block_content\Entity\BlockContentType;
use Drupal\field\Entity\FieldConfig;
use Drupal\field\Entity\FieldStorageConfig;

function <your_module_name>_install() {
  $newBlockType = BlockContentType::create([
    'id' => <your_id>,
    'label' => 'Custom block type',
    'description' => "A custom block type",
  ]);
  $newBlockType->save();

  $blockId = $newBlockType->id();

  block_content_add_field($blockId, 'Icon', 'custom_block_icon', 'image', 'image', 'image_image');
  block_content_add_field($blockId, 'Count', 'custom_block_count', 'integer', 'number_integer', 'number');
  block_content_add_field($blockId, 'Description', 'custom_block_description', 'text', 'text_default', 'text_textfield');

}
function block_content_add_field(
  $blockTypeId,
  $label,
  $componentName,
  $fieldStorageType,
  $viewDisplayType = 'text_default',
  $formDisplayType = 'text_textarea_with_summary') {
    // Add or remove the body field, as needed.
    $field = FieldConfig::loadByName('block_content', $blockTypeId, $componentName);
    if (empty($field)) {
      $fieldStorage = FieldStorageConfig::loadByName('block_content', $componentName);
      if (empty($fieldStorage)) {
        $fieldStorage = FieldStorageConfig::create([
          'field_name' => $componentName,
          'entity_type' => 'block_content',
          'type' => $fieldStorageType,
        ]);
        $fieldStorage->save();
      }

      $field = FieldConfig::create([
        'field_storage' => $fieldStorage,
        'bundle' => $blockTypeId,
        'label' => $label,
        'settings' => ['display_summary' => FALSE],
      ]);

      $field->save();

      /** @var \Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityDisplayRepositoryInterface $display_repository */
      $display_repository = \Drupal::service('entity_display.repository');

      // Assign widget settings for the default form mode.
      $display_repository->getFormDisplay('block_content', $blockTypeId)
        ->setComponent($componentName, [
          'type' => $formDisplayType,
        ])
        ->save();

      // Assign display settings for default view mode.
      $display_repository->getViewDisplay('block_content', $blockTypeId)
        ->setComponent($componentName, [
          'label' => 'hidden',
          'type' => $viewDisplayType,
        ])
        ->save();
    }

    return $field;
}
```

Result: the new custom block type with 3 fields.

Comment: Danyil - did you place your code in a your_module.install file? Can you share a little more about the module part. Tryin to learn this and this is the most complete information I can find and still a push. I added this to a module I have for a custom block plugin. But this threw an error... thanks!

Comment: So, I wanted to add this to Danyil's answer. I need to get something working. I added connections to classes and was able to get the Block to install in Custom Block Types on my site. use Drupal\block_content\Entity\BlockContentType; use Drupal\Core\Block\Blockbase; use Drupal\field\Entity\FieldConfig; use Drupal\field\Entity\FieldStorageConfig; use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityStorage; Hope this helps someone!

Comment: @timwhelan
Yes, I did. Ex: your module name is coolModule
so, create a file 
coolModule.install 
and inside it write a hook
function coolModule_install(){}

Answer (score 1):

You can create content block type using configuration files:
In you module should have `config/install/block_content.type.YOUR_BLOCK_TYPE_MACHINE_NAME.yml`
see the following example from core for ***Basic block*** `core/profiles/standard/config/install/block_content.type.basic.yml` .

Here is an example to create new type called ***My Block Type***

1. Go to *admin/structure/block/block-content/types*
   Create by clicking on **Add custom block type**
2. Create fields you want by **Manage Fields**
3. To export your configuration Go to *admin/config/development/configuration/single/export*
   [image]
   And Create a config file in your Module and put in it the result:
   *YOURMODULENAME/config/install/block_content.type.my_block_type.yml*
4. And also you should export fields associated to your block type:
   the same way you did with block type config:
   Go to *admin/config/development/configuration/single/export* 
   choose **Field** as configuration type and choose all **Configuration name** with name **block_content.my_block_type.FIELD_NAME** like the body field below 
   [image] and then the **Field Storage** configuration.

Or you can export configuration using Drupal console like the following:

```
drupal config:export:entity block_content my_block_type --module="YOURMODULENAME" --optional-config --remove-uuid --remove-config-hash --include-module-dependencies
```

Answer (score 0):

An easier way to do this would be to:

1. Add `block_content` module as a dependency to your custom module
2. Create the configuration you want and export it, pay attention to the config files created for step 3 below.
3. Add the exported config to your module under `your_module/config/install`. You can use config_devel for that to make your life easier.
4. Enable your module.

This goes more towards the Drupal 7 Features, but it is quite easier to handle and to maintain.

The .info.yml file will have these lines in the end if you use config_devel:

```
dependecies:
  - block_content

config_devel:
  - block_content.type.html_block
  - language.content_settings.block_content.html_block
  - field.field.block_content.html_block.body
  - core.entity_view_display.block_content.html_block.default
  - core.entity_form_display.block_content.html_block.default
```

I had to add 5 files in my case (one field, with translations enabled).